# Expanding inverse of a function

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion, binomial-theorem

Apparently the expansion to this function is equal to the following -

$(1-\phi{z})^{-1} = 1 + \phi{z} + \phi^{2}z^{2} + ....$

But I can't see why that is. I have a feeling the answer is extremely trivial and obvious.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Geometric series.

Comment: Of course! Thank you!!